# Plotting rows from different dataframes in a single chart in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently trying to plot rows of data from 2 different charts into a single plot, however, the plots i am getting are all blank.

Here is a sample code i made which leads to a similar structure to what i am using and yields the same results:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data1 = [[0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.9, 0.5, '1'], [0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.6, '2']]
data2 = [[0.6, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, '1'], [0.2, 0.3, 0.9, 0.6, 0.7, 0.2, '2']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','cluster'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','cluster'])

Xc = np.array(df1[['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6']])
Xv = np.array(df2[['h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6']])

uniquevalues = np.unique(df1[['cluster']].values)

for i in uniquevalues:
    for curve in Xc[('cluster' == i)]:
        plt.plot(curve.ravel(), "r-")
    for curves in Xv[('cluster' == i)]:
        plt.plot(curves.ravel(), "k-", alpha=0.5)
    plt.savefig('plot_{}.png'.format(i))
    plt.close()
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not referencing the dataframes correctly. You need this:

```
for curve in Xc[df1['cluster'] == i]:
    plt.plot(curve.ravel(), "r-")
for curves in Xv[df2['cluster'] == i]:
    plt.plot(curves.ravel(), "k-", alpha=0.5)
```

Your code was just asking if 'cluster' was equal to i which it never was, since 'cluster' is a string and the values in the dataframes are 1 and 2.